# slowquery what's wrong?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, key

I caught this query on the slowquerys log.

```
SELECT GREATEST( IFNULL(`twk-status`.`status`,0) , `groups`.`status`)
FROM `groups` 
LEFT JOIN `twk-status` ON
    (`twk-status`.`groupID` = `groups`.`ID`
    AND `twk-status`.`startdate` <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1317204000)
    AND `twk-status`.`enddate` >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1317204000)
    AND ISNULL(`twk-status`.`deleted`)
    AND `twk-status`.`groupID` = 11)
WHERE `groups`.`ID` = 11;
```

I ran the query using EXPLAIN producing the following report:

```
id  table       possible_keys                  key 
1   twk-status  groupID,groupID_2,enddate      NULL
1   groups      PRIMARY                        PRIMARY
```

This mean that mysql didn't used any of the three possible keys for **twk-status** table. Correct?

Here's the keys from twk-status

```
groupID (groupID)
groupID_2 (groupID, startdate, enddate, deleted)  
enddate (enddate, createdate, deleted)
```

The query uses **groupID, startdate, enddate, deleted** I thought groupID_2 whould be the key.

Or is this a query problem and not a index problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This `EXPLAIN` is very strange. Could you please post the definitions of the tables and **exact** output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Which version of `MySQL` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From your explain I can judge that the order or tables is swapped.

For each record from `twk-status` a corresponding record from `groups` is being searched, since you have a `PRIMARY KEY` join condition among the others (`twk-status.groupID = groups.ID`)

However, I'm almost sure that there is something wrong with this `EXPLAIN`, because `MySQL` is not able to swap the order for `LEFT JOIN`.

Could you please post the exact output of `EXPLAIN`?

**Update:**

When building the plans, `MySQL` checks existence of constant values searched in indexed fields.

Some of these checks failed. It's impossible to tell which exactly, but you either don't have `groupID = 11` in `twk-status` or a record with `enddate >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1317204000)`.

`MySQL` just replaced the whole join with an empty row value for `twk-status`, and will return it along with the data for group with `groupID = 11`.

Comment: Results too big, here's a screenshot 
http://img141.imageshack.us/i/picture1cw.png/

Comment: hummmmm ... the query is returning 0 rows. When I perform this manually and it executes in 0.003 seconds. Why was this logged has slowquery then? Do you have a guess? No rows where deleted.

Comment: @cmancre: actually, `const row not found` would be thrown only if `twk-status` was empty. Hard to say why was it logged as slow. Is the table `MyISAM` or `InnoDB`? Could it be locked?

Comment: MyISAM
No locks applied for sure.
I'll keep an eye on this query do see if it triggers a slowquery again.

Comment: @cmancre: long update operations would lock the table in `MyISAM`.